# ASP.NET web app loads as local user instead of Azure AD login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to migrate from local NLTM authentication to Azure AD login for an on premise app. I have set up the connected service, but everytime the SignIn method is called:
[image]

The request is already authenticated and it's using my local PC name, so the O365 log in is never triggered. Debugging doesn't help as the User info and Request don't seem to exist outside of the AccountController. Does anyone know what is going on and how I can get it to load up the login instead?

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code.

Comment: You _probably_ should not be using Azure AD to authenticate your application against the database server itself - dealing with NTLM/Kerberos impersonation with SQL Server is difficult enough (SPIs, anyone?), Azure AD even more-so. Is there a reason you can't use an application database user instead?

Comment: Also, NTLM/Kerberos and Azure AD are **so different in so many ways** you really shouldn't think of Azure AD as a "replacement" or migration-target away from NTLM. Indeed, **Azure AD is not replacing NTLM/Kerberos**.  One is for local Active Directory security, the other is for public internet SSO using OIDC/OAuth2 (and SAML/WS-Federation). I know SQL Server has built-in support for Azure AD but... I dont' think it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else finds this, check and triple check your web config and project files for any lingering windows authentication variables. Failing that try creating a new project with authentication and then copy the content of the old project across bit by bit. It turned out for me to be something dodgy in the project, but even using a comparison tool afterwards showed no discernible differences.

Only thing I can think of is that the Authentication with Azure Active Directory Connected Services made changes that broke something, but using the auth option during project creation did it properly.